# TypeScript. OnClick event type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Getting a type error on my function to open a nav menu.

```
  const onMenuOpen = (e: React.KeyboardEvent): void => {
    const currentTarget = e.currentTarget
    setAnchorEl(currentTarget);
  };
```

The error states `Argument of type 'EventTarget & Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<null>'`

I'm new to typescript and really not sure what this error is telling me.

Comment: Please show how you declared `setAnchorEl`.

Comment: You read (most) TS errors as `Argument of type <what you wrote in your code> is not assignable to parameter of type <what the function you're calling actually wants>` so in this case the TS error is telling you that you're calling a function that wants a `SetStateAction<null>` as argument (namely, the `setAnchroEl` function) completely the wrong thing. In this case, you're giving it an event target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says `currentTarget` type is `EventTarget & Element`.
However, the allowed type for `setStateAction` is `null`, so the error is caused by a type mismatch.

maybe your code is

```
const [stateAction, setStateAction] = useState(null)
```

Set the correct type

```
const [stateAction, setStateAction] = useState<Element | null>(null)
```